# opacity with an overlay div

Tags: html, css, overlay, opacity

[image: SS]

I am currently working on an "overlay pop up", which appears when I click a certain button.

It works quite well, however I struggle with the `opacity`

My main overlay `div` appears over the whole site and I gave it an `opacity`, so that you can see slightly the page in the `background`.

Over the overlay I put a content `div`, which shows the actual content (in that case a password changing request).

Anyway, I don't want the content box being transparent, but no matter what I try (`z-index:10`, `opacity:1`, `position:relative` etc.) it doesn't work.

It is still transparent, because I set up the `opacity` in the overlay div.

Here is the code:

CSS:

```
.changePasswordOverlay
{
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color:#fafafa;
    opacity: 0.9;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 1s;
}

.passwordOverlayContent {
    margin-left:40%;
    margin-top:15%;
    font-family:'source_sans_proregular';
    font-size:15px;  
    position:relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="changePasswordOverlay">
        <div class='passwordOverlayContent'>
        .
        .
        .
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to use `rgba` in `background` instead of `opacity`, because `opacity` has inheritance properties therefore children will get `opacity` as well

Note that `rgba`, stands for Red/Green/Blue/Alpha. and that's the alpha value that will work as your "opacity" value. The greater the alpha value the more opaque will be.

```css
.changePasswordOverlay {
  height: 100%; /* changed for demo */
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
}
.passwordOverlayContent {
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-top: 15%;
  font-family: 'source_sans_proregular';
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  color:white /* demo */
}
```

```html
<div class="changePasswordOverlay">
  <div class='passwordOverlayContent'>
     text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Opacity applied the `div` and its `children` so `.passwordOverlayContent` will also have the same `opacity`, use `background rgba` instead of `opacity`

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
```

changed class :

```
.changePasswordOverlay
{
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

move the `passwordOverlayContent` container after `changePasswordOverlay` (instead of inside), and change your css to `position:fixed` to make it "opacity independant"